# x86: EAX contains value of 1 but cmp eax, 1 gives false

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, nasm, cmp

I have such part of code

```
cmp eax, [SPHERE]
je VolumeSphere
```

I use the variable `SPHERE` and it's like enum for `1`.
Also, I check what is in `eax` and it `1` too(by `printf`).
So, I have changed the code to this and it's giving me `false` too(`je` didn't work and `jne` work):

```
cmp eax, 1
je VolumeSphere
```

Eax must contain `1`, coz it definitely points to place in memory, where I write/read from file value 1. But in this situation comparison is `false`.

So, I start debugging with gdb. More detailed code:

```
mov [cont], rdi                       ; I saving address of array / rdi contains 4211776
mov [len], rsi                        ; Length of array

mov r9, 0                             ; It will be counter for calling cont[r9]
mov rsi, 0
mov rdi, 0                            ; each elem of struc takes 20 bytes
lea rsi, [r9 + r9*4]
lea rdi, [cont + rsi*4]               ; rdi contains 4412024
call ....
```

into method

```
mov eax, [rdi]                        ;rdi must contains beginning of cont[r9](cont[0])
cmp eax, 1                            ; rdi and eax contains 4211776
je VolumeSphere                       ; after cmp PF IF RF change to PF AF IF RF
```

if I try to check eax by gdb it writes:

```
p $eax
    $1 = 4211776
x/s 0x404440
    0x404440 <cont>: "\001"
x/s 4211776
    0x404440 <cont>: "\001"
```

Even if I try to compare `eax` with `001` or `4211776` its gives `false`.

And this is all I do in my code after getting into it. All registers are copied and get 0. I didn't have any idea why it can have such behavior. I really need help, so if I can find more information in code/gdb, say what u need.

I post full code [in the cloud](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/iyXtZAWGUcRfRQ). The same part of code I use in output.asm(117), inrnd.asm(133), input.asm(131).

Comment: `eax` doesn't contain 1, it points to memory containing a 1. Also that memory location may change between each run.

Comment: @ecm so how I need to use `cmp` in this situation? In the other part of the code `cmp eax, [SPHERE]`  is working.

Comment: Copy the value in the other variable to another register (say, `ebx`) then either `cmp dword [eax], ebx` or `cmp word [eax], bx` or `cmp byte [eax], bl` (depending on the size of your variable).

Comment: @ecm it didn't work too. It ignores je and ZF = 0.

Comment: `x/s` is for strings. Use `x/w` or similar. Also, if `eax` is supposed to be a pointer, you likely want to use 64 bit `rax`, and already while loading it.

Comment: What size is `SPHERE`?  Are you sure it is a dword?  (I can't easily see the code you linked to; clicking files doesn't open them, and I can't tell how to do anything else because I can't read Russian. If you can make a [mcve] and include it in your post, that would be best.)